# What's a compiler friendly and endian-agnostic way to write this?

Tags: c, memory, endianness

I have some code on an embedded system. The code can be seen here [link](https://github.com/avrxml/asf/blob/master/sam0/drivers/nvm/nvm.c), particularly this snippet:

```
uint32_t raw_fusebits[2];
....
/* Read the fuse settings in the user row, 64 bit */
((uint16_t*)&raw_fusebits)[0] = (uint16_t)NVM_MEMORY[NVMCTRL_USER / 2];
((uint16_t*)&raw_fusebits)[1] = (uint16_t)NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 1];
((uint16_t*)&raw_fusebits)[2] = (uint16_t)NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 2];
((uint16_t*)&raw_fusebits)[3] = (uint16_t)NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 3];
```

This causes a compiler warning under C99 related to strict-aliasing. Is there a better way to write this? At first I thought (using some simpler variable names for readability):

```
uint32_t x[2];
uint16_t a, b, c, d;
x[0] = ((uint32_t)a << 16) | ((uint32_t)b);
x[1] = ((uint32_t)c << 16) | ((uint32_t)d);
```

And then I switched to,

```
x[0] = ((uint32_t)b << 16) | ((uint32_t)a);
x[1] = ((uint32_t)d << 16) | ((uint32_t)c);
```

Which is correct but on my little-endian machine. And then I confused myself by wondering why endianness didn't apply when I tested these with certain values.

Is there a compiler-friendly way to rewrite the library code to be endian-agnostic?

edit: On line 73, you can see the definition for NVM_MEMORY, so the size is consistent there at least.

```
#define NVM_MEMORY        ((volatile uint16_t *)FLASH_ADDR)
```

Comment: What's the byte order (or word order) of the target of `NVM_MEMORY`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
memcpy(raw_fusebits, NVM_MEMORY + (NVMCTRL_USER / 2), sizeof(raw_fusebits));
```

Given that the fields are copied as-is, 16 bits at a time, it doesn't seem like there's any endianness handling in the original code.  And using `memcpy()` avoids the strict-aliasing problem.

Comment: You're missing at least a  `&` for `NVM_MEMORY` (whose type is unknown, so pointer arithmetic is a bit iffy). Also, `sizeof` is not a function. :)

Comment: NVM_MEMORY is defined, forgot to point that out. Same link, line 73.

Comment: @unwind: am I really missing a `&`?  `NVM_MEMORY` is `((volatile uint16_t *)FLASH_ADDR)`, and the way it was used in the OP's code makes it seem like it's a pointer to the beginning of an array, so I think my code is OK.  Regarding `sizeof()`, I used to omit the `()` too, but found it more consistent to use them with values since types require them anyway.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Nope, then it's fine of course, I didn't notice the link. For the record I think it's a good idea to include declarations of all variables used in a question (except perhaps `argv` and `argc`). Yeah, I know many people seem to value consistency in that case. I just try to point it out since even more people seem to think it's a function, and reinforcing that creates confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just use `memcpy` as suggested by John. But if the values you need to assign are calculated, `memcpy` won't be sufficient. In that case, a compiler-friendly way to alias values supported by C is using a `union`:

```
union {
  struct {
    uint32_t val[2];
  } u32;
  struct {
    uint16_t val[4];
  } u16;
} raw;
...
raw.u16.val[0] = NVM_MEMORY[NVMCTRL_USER / 2];
raw.u16.val[1] = NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 1];
raw.u16.val[2] = NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 2];
raw.u16.val[3] = NVM_MEMORY[(NVMCTRL_USER / 2) + 3];

/* obtain 32-bit values from raw.u32.val[0] and raw.u32.val[1] */
```

Comment: "But if the values you need to assign are calculated, memcpy won't be sufficient". Could you explain this? And neat solution.

Comment: @Ben In your case, you are simply copying data, i.e. accessing `NVM_MEMORY[NVMCTRL_USER / 2]`, `NVM_MEMORY[NVMCTRL_USER / 2 + 1]`, and so forth, and assigning it to the target. If you needed to do some calculation before assignment, e.g. sum the values, or multiply them by some constant, you couldn't do that with `memcpy`, but the solution from this answer would still work.